# SSL query when using JQuery and PhoneGap

Tags: android, ssl, https, webview, cordova

I'm developing an app that uses JQuery Mobile and PhoneGap. My program makes ajax calls using jquery ($.ajax(.....)) to https addresses and also uses the ChildBrowser plugin to display remote pages from the same address.

During development I'm connecting to a development server with a self-signed SSL cert. While my call to display a page in the ChildBrowser responsds with the typical "This certificate is not from a trusted authority" and "Hostname verification" warnings, the ajax calls from the WebView work without any problems. While this makes development easier I'm concerned that may be a potential security hole.

Has anyone come across this? To date I've only tested on the Android emulator, but I'm not expecting any different behaviour.

Thanks,
Eoin

Answer (score 1):

the "android:debuggable" attribute was set to true in my Manifest file. Setting this to false gives the expected warnings.